# Forward systemd journal messages/Collect systemd journal messages

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, journald

How can I collect systemd journal events (pull) or forward systemd journal events (push)?

I want to have something like forwarded event log (http://windows.tips.net/T012878_What_is_the_Purpose_of_the_Forwarded_Events_Event_Log.html) but under Linux.

I'm using ArchLinux but not sure this matters.

Should I forward journal to syslog and then collect syslog? Will I loose any info by doing so? Can I collect journal messages without syslog daemon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forwarding messages to legacy software like syslog gives you nothing but overhead.

Instead you can implement both models using native journald features.

Push model:

(log source) systemd-journal-upload -> systemd-journal-remote (log collector)

Pull model:

(log source) systemd-journal-gatewayd <- systemd-journal-remote (log collector)

The arrow shows who initiates the connection. HTTPS is used as a transport so it's secure.

The more information can be obtained from:

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.html

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-upload.html

and so on.

Comment: A note to anyone who arrives here via Google while using Debian 8: If you're running a resource-constrained VPS, **test your logging solution** (using `while true; do echo 'test string' | systemd-cat; done`). I was forced to rely on `Storage=none` and forwarding to `inetutils-syslogd` because it was the only way to keep `systemd-journald` from treating memory limits as a loose suggestion. (peaking at 7.7% RSS while the syslog-based solution sits steady at 0.8% (`systemd-journald`) + 0.7% (`syslogd --no-forward --socket=/run/systemd/journal/syslog`). You'll also want `logrotate` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Both `syslog` or `rsyslog` are a good idea, both can handle local and remote logging. It's usually done using UDP, so yes, messages can be lost. `rsyslog` can be configured to use TCP and even TLS, though.

You could have a hybrid deployment, e.g. have syslog as sender and rsyslog as receiver.

With syslog you can write something like:

```
*.*;*.!notice   @192.168.100.220
```

in `/etc/syslog.conf` on sender and

```
$ModLoad imudp.so
$UDPServerRun 514
```

in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` on receiver and get all your messages collected on receiver.

Answer (score -1):

How about deploying logstash or fluentd to collect your logs and may be you can forward them later to syslog, splung, appDynamics ...etc or any legacy software